# Is it possible for an Android app to get contacts of another Android user?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-user-profile

Given the Android device has 2 users. Each of this users will have it's own contacts lists and installed applications.

Is it possible for the application installed by only one of this users to read the contacts of another one?

Comment: you can access the google contacts of any account using google auth.

Comment: And what if this two users will have different google accounts (they probably will) and both will switch off automatic contant syncronization?